# Learning R - What is this Function Doing?

Tags: r, function

I am learning R and reading the book Guide to programming algorithms in r.

The book give an example function:

```
# MATRIX-VECTOR MULTIPLICATION
matvecmult = function(A,x){
    m = nrow(A)
    n = ncol(A) 
    y = matrix(0,nrow=m)
    for (i in 1:m){
        sumvalue = 0        
        for (j in 1:n){
            sumvalue = sumvalue + A[i,j]*x[j]
        }
        y[i] = sumvalue
    }
    return(y)
}
```

How do I call this function in the R console?  And what exactly is passing into this function A, X?

Comment: What exactly is not clear for you in here? It does not have any R-specific features, it is straightforward and you have even pasted a "title" that describes what it does. Also `A` and `x` parameters are coherent with how matrices and variables are described in matrix notation...

Comment: This should only be used as a programming exercise. It's a very inefficient method of doing this: `A %*% cbind(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function takes an argument `A`, which should be a matrix, and `x`, which should be a numeric vector of same length as values per row in `A`.

If

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

then you have 3 values (number of columns, `ncol`) per row, thus `x` needs to be something like

```
x <- c(4,5,6)
```

The function itself iterates all rows, and in each row, each value is multiplied with a value from `x`, where the value in the first column is multiplied with the first value in `x`, the value in `A`s second column is multiplied with the second value in `x` and so on. This is repeated for each row, and the `sum` for each row is returned by the function.

```
matvecmult(A, x)

     [,1]
[1,]   49 # 1*4 + 3*5 + 5*6
[2,]   64 # 2*4 + 4*5 + 6*6
```

To run this function, you first have to compile (source) it and then consecutively run these three code lines:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
x <- c(4,5,6)
matvecmult(A, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is designed to return the product of a matrix `A` with a vector `x`; i.e. the result will be the *matrix product* `A` `x` (where - as is usual in R, the vector is a *column* vector).  An example should make things clear.

```
# define a matrix
mymatrix <- matrix(sample(12), nrow <- 4) 

# see what the matrix looks like
mymatrix

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2   10    9
# [2,]    3    1   12
# [3,]   11    7    5
# [4,]    8    4    6

# define a vector where multiplication of our matrix times the vector will be defined
vec3 <- c(-1,0,1)

# apply the function to our matrix and vector
result <- matvecmult(mymatrix, vec3) 
result
#       [,1]
# [1,]    7
# [2,]    9
# [3,]   -6
# [4,]   -2

class(result)
# [1] "matrix"
```

So `matvecmult(mymatrix, vec3)` is how you would call this function, and the result is an *n* by 1 matrix, where *n* is the number of rows in the matrix argument.

You can also get some insight by playing around and seeing what happens when you pass something other than a matrix-vector pair where the product is defined.  In some cases, you will get an error; sometimes you get nonsense; and sometimes you get something you might not expect just from the function name.  See what happens when you call `matvecmult(mymatrix, mymatrix)`.

Answer (score 0):

The function is calculating the product of a Matrix and a column vector. It assumes both the number of columns of the matrix is equal to the number of elements in the vector.

It stores the number of columns of `A` in `n` and number of rows in `m`.

It then initializes a matrix of `m`rows with all values as `0`.

It iterates along the rows of `A` and multiplies each value in each row with the values in `x`.

The answer is the stored in `y` and finally it returns the single column matrix `y`.